# I have 3 rows Count, Number and value coming in from a source but the order is not confirmed, how do I align them in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I query these values between specific datetime and the values appear in any order sorted by the datetime. Sometimes the Weight might be missed and the Count and Number might appear.

```
Name    Value    Datetime 
Weight  48.8     10/24/2021  8:34:52:053 PM
Count   18       10/24/2021  8:34:52:460 PM
Number  40015516 10/24/2021  8:34:52:553 PM
Weight  48.82    10/24/2021  8:34:59:063 PM
Number  40015518 10/24/2021  8:34:59:563 PM
Count   19       10/24/2021  8:35:00:470 PM
```

I want the result to be in following way with the date being the maximum date from the set of values.

```
Datetime                      Number    Count   Weight
10/24/2021 8:34:52:553 PM   40015516    18      48.8
10/24/2021 8:35:00:470 PM   40015518    19      48.82
```

So far I tried to use `Ntile` function to split the data into Buckets and loop through the data using the buckets and read the values as columns. The issue is that some times either the Number or count or weight is missing in source data and its causing the issues. And also the data is not always in the same order from the source.

I am doing count('*) from the source and dividing it by 3 and using the Ntile function

```
select  @bucketCount =  count(*)/3
from #SourceTable 

insert into #Temptable
select
  Name,
  value,
  Date_time,
  NTILE (@bucketCount) OVER (
        ORDER BY id
    ) buckets
from #Sourcetable
```

Comment: Thanks Dale, Images are cooked up data to help  understand my question.

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) link.

Comment: Looks like you want a _crosstab_

Comment: This is a pivot problem but I'm confused how you get these sets of three rows to correlate to each other. Remember, tables have no inherent order, so how do you know if `Weight  48.8` goes with `Count   18` rather than `Count   19`

Comment: The sample data is missing the cruicial information that identifies the grouping for each set of rows.

Comment: I understand but the data from source comes from 3 different points depending on the time which ever count comes in first should be associated with the first weight

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier if the source data could be grouped by exact times.

With the slight differences in time you could use a Gaps and Islands approach to group chronologically within a small margin of error, e.g.: 2 seconds...

```sql
create table #SourceTable (
  Name nvarchar(10),
  [Value] float, --<<-- WARNING: floats are approximate
  [Datetime] datetime
);

insert #SourceTable (Name, [Value], [Datetime]) values
  (N'Weight', 48.8, '2021-10-24T20:34:52.053'),
  (N'Count', 18, '2021-10-24T20:34:52.460'),
  (N'Number', 40015516, '2021-10-24T20:34:52.553'),
  (N'Weight', 48.82, '2021-10-24T20:34:59.063'),
  (N'Number', 40015518, '2021-10-24T20:34:59.563'),
  (N'Count', 19, '2021-10-24T20:35:00.470');

with LagsAndLeads as (
  select
    [Datetime],
    lag([DateTime]) over (order by [Datetime]) as Previous,
    lead([DateTime]) over (order by [Datetime]) as Next
  from #SourceTable
), IslandStarts as (
  select
    row_number() over (order by [Datetime]) as IslandNumber,
    [Datetime] as IslandStart
  from LagsAndLeads
  where datediff(second, Previous, [Datetime]) >= 2
  or Previous is null
), IslandEnds as (
  select
    row_number() over (order by [Datetime]) as IslandNumber,
    [DateTime] as IslandEnd
  from LagsAndLeads
  where datediff(second, [Datetime], Next) >= 2
  or Next is null
), Chronology as (
  select
    S.Name, S.[Value], S.[Datetime], Starts.IslandNumber, IslandStart, IslandEnd
  from IslandStarts Starts
  join IslandEnds Ends on Ends.IslandNumber=Starts.IslandNumber
  join #SourceTable S on S.[Datetime] >= IslandStart and S.[Datetime] <= IslandEnd
)
select [IslandEnd] as [Datetime], [Number], [Count], [Weight]
from (
  select [IslandEnd], [Name], [Value]
  from Chronology
) Src
pivot (max([Value]) for Name in ([Number], [Count], [Weight])) as Pvt;
```

Which yields the results:

| Datetime | Number | Count | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-24 20:34:52.553 | 40015516 | 18 | 48.8 |
| 2021-10-24 20:35:00.470 | 40015518 | 19 | 48.82 |